# Do I need to use "some" when I use "such as"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I wrote:

> In this window, **[some?]** dynamic properties such as color, font name, font weight and **[some?]** calculated values such as link density, text length, text density are provided in addition to the element’s static attributes such as ID, class and name.

Do I need to or can I use the "some"s (shown in brackets)?

Comment: In my opinion, you need at least the *first* instance of ***some*** unless you want the implication that *all* dynamic properties are provided (to me, that would be the default interpretation without ***some***, but opinions may differ). You don't really need to repeat it in the second position, since it would be contextually unlikely a reader would assume all *calculated* values are also provided.

Comment: You can use some but you have to use both or none.

Comment: In my opinion , you can use the first `some` , but the second one looks strange to me .

Comment: I don't like the verb "provided" there. Does the window *provide* these attributes? Or does it show|display them?

Comment: To add an opinion differing from that of @FumbleFingers: Even if you don't use "some", you won't necessarily imply that all dynamic properties are provided. But it depends on the context, specifically: Is this the kind of situation in which there's only one place where these properties are provided? If so, it means "all". If not, it doesn't have to.

Comment: @Luke Sawczak: Strictly speaking, it's ambiguous whether ***some/all** calculated values* are provided, if the preceding text specifically references ***some**  dynamic properties*, since there's no rule saying whether or not the scope of that "quantifier" extends to a second referent after ***and***. But if it was necessary to make an "educated guess", I'd always assume it *did* extend, since the writer could easily have specified ***calculated values*** first, followed by ***and some dynamic properties***, if he wanted to ensure ***some*** unambiguously applied ***only*** to that category.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed. I was just thinking about the dynamic properties and not the calculated values at all in regards to whether the lack of "some" implies "all".

Answer (score 1):

Two examples of "such as" in a sentence, from the Cambridge dictionary, don't use "some." It doesn't flow as easily and tends to sound not so much like a redundancy but like a word or phrase which in common usage is left out but is understood or implied.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you typically don't need to use *some* in front of words and phrases that are fallowed by *such as*.

Example:

> The Roman alphabet is used in many modern languages **such as** French, English and German.

Why is that true? I think it's because when we're talking about some of something, we imply that there is still some more of it left that we decided not to include in the group that we're interested in considering. So, *some dynamic properties such as* implies that there are other properties in the whole list of all available properties not explicitly mentioned that are not provided in addition to blah blah blah.

I'm not sure if my explanation makes perfect sense.